# How to install the missing countries

Tags: custom-fields

When adding a new contact, I want to insert the address including the country. However, in the drop-down menu, only a few countries are listed.
How can I add missing countries to the drop-down menu at the address field?

Answer (score 4):

From the CiviCRM menu -

Administer > Localization > Languages, Currency, Location.

Select required countries from the 'Available Countries' option.

CiviCRM help on this option -

*Which countries are available in the Country selection field when adding or editing contact addresses. Profile and Custom 'Country' fields also use this setting. To include ALL countries, leave the right-hand box empty.*